# how to use Promise.all method?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I'm having problems using Promise.all When I try to loop through the array to turn the elements into json it does not work, can someone explain me why It does not work?

```
function getData() {

let getUsers = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
let getTodos = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
Promise.all([getUsers, getTodos])
   .then(data => {
          data.forEach(item => {
            item.json()
            console.log(item)});
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
}; 
getData();
```

Comment: `Promise.all` on an array of `fetch` calls will give you an array of fetch response objects, which will have `json` methods - it's not clear what you were expecting to happen when you logged `item`.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not  work"?  What error are you getting?  Is it a network or JS error?  Put the error in your question as text.

Comment: You also aren't doing anything with `item.json()` (which also returns a `Promise`).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `async function`?

Comment: `item.json()` does not change or modify `item` and you do not "keep" the returned data (which is *not* json!).

Comment: There are good examples on `fetch` when you read the documentation... but you have to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all()` takes an array of Promises and [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) a Promise that resolves to an array of values returned by promises.

For example:

```
const promiseA = Promise.resolve('valueA');
const promiseB = Promise.resolve('valueB');

Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB]).then(data => {
   console.log(data); // [ 'valueA', 'valueB' ]
})
```

So `data` is an array `[ users, todos ]` (where `users` is result of `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')`)

```
function getData() {

let getUsers = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => response.json())
let getTodos = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => response.json())

Promise.all([getUsers, getTodos])
   .then(data => {
         const [users, todos] = data;
          users.forEach(user => {
            console.log(user)
          });
          todos.(todo => {
            console.log(todo)
          });
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
}; 
getData();
```

Answer (score -1):

Better idea: Change your JavaScript to use `async function` which means you don't need to use `Promise.all` at all, like so:

```
async function getData() {

    const usersPromise = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const todosPromise = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');

    const users = await usersPromise;
    const todos = await todosPromise;

    for( const todo of todos ) {
        console.log( todo );
    }
}

getData();
```